# R: dplR, chron to extract smoothed chronology

Tags: r

I am working with the `detrend` function in the `dplR` package to detrend a tree ring database using the negative exponential / negative linear method.

`dt.rwi <- detrend(rwl=d, verbose=TRUE, 
              method="ModNegExp", pos.slope = FALSE)`

I then build a chronology from the detrended values in each series, smoothed with the `nyrs=30` command.

`neg.crn <- chron(dt.rwi, biweight = TRUE, prewhiten = FALSE, nyrs=30)`

**The problem** is that when I print the `neg.crn` object, I only get the mean detrended index for each year, not the smoothed values.  The plot returns the smoothed line, but again, I can't extract the data used to construct this line.

`plot(neg.crn, add.spline=T, nyrs=30)`

**How do I print the values used to create the smoothed line from either the `chron` or `plot` functions?**

Answer (score 1):

That's not complicate,

I don't know why the chron() function doesn't give out the smoothed values.
However, you can use the ffcsaps() function from the same package to get this smoothed values.

Example:

Add a new column with the smoothed values in your dataframe using the ffcsaps() function.

```
neg.crn$smooth32 <- ffcsaps(neg.crn[,1], nyrs = 32) # that is all! Now just check these values in your dataframe.
```

Test it plotting your data

```
plot(neg.crn[,1], type = "l")
lines(neg.crn$smooth32, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

tell me if it worked for you
Cheers